# Code Help for Visual Basic Radio buttons and If Else Statements

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I am working on building a program in Visual Basic that when one Radio button is selected and Display is clicked, it will show the capital of that state. I keep getting Errors even for some of my code that has worked well before. Please help if you can. I am still learning so thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```vb
Option Explicit On
Option Strict Off
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
        Dim lblOne.Text As String

        If btnTexas.Checked Then
            lblOne.Text = " Austin"

        ElseIf btnOhio.Checked Then
            lblOne.Text = "Columbus"

        ElseIf btnFlorida.Checked Then
            lblOne.Text = "Tallahassee"

        ElseIf btnAlabama.Checked Then
            lblOne.Text = "Montgomery"

        ElseIf btnArizona.Checked Then
            lblOne.Text = "Phoenix"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here are the Errors:

> Error BC30205 End of statement expected.  12  Active
>
> Error BC30506 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.  10, 31  Active
>
> Error BC30451 'btnTexas' 'btnOhio' 'btnFlorida' 'btnAlabama' 'btnArizona' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
>
> Error BC30456 'Close' is not a member of 'frmMain'.
>
> Warning   BC42104 Variable 'lblOne' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.  Capitals Project

Comment: Get rid of this line: `Dim lblOne.Text As String`, then report back on the new errors listed.

Comment: I still get these three errors: Error BC30506 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types. 10, 31 Active

Error BC30451 'btnTexas' 'btnOhio' 'btnFlorida' 'btnAlabama' 'btnArizona' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Error BC30456 'Close' is not a member of 'frmMain'.

Comment: I managed to figure it out! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

On your form, you must have two buttons named "**btnDisplay**" and "**btnExit**"
and a label named "**lblOne**"
and ChecBoxes with named each of these, "'**btnTexas**' '**btnOhio**' '**btnFlorida**' '**btnAlabama**' '**btnArizona**'"

Comment: I have already done all of that. Which is why I don't understand why I am getting the error.

Comment: Something must be wrong between your Form1.Desinger.vb and your Form1.vb. In your form, you have something like "Public Class Form1" and in the designer you should have something like "Partial Class Form1"  Do the class names match?

Comment: I figured out what went wrong. For some reason the recent update was messing up my code. Thank you so much!